# How to use support version of recycler view instead of Androidx

Tags: android, gradle, android-recyclerview, build.gradle

I was using androidx recycler view. But now I want to use support version of recycler view. I have removed androidx dependency and added support dependency in gradle. The sync works well. But now the ide is not showing me android.support.widget.recyclerview. it is still showing androidx.recylerview.widget.recyclerview.  what should I do?

Comment: Have you tried clean build in android studio?

Comment: Yes but it doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are you are using androidx library you can use only androidx library , i.e android does not support both android x and support library at the same time, so you need to change all android x library to support librarys

refer this link https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate/artifact-mappings

Comment: Thanks it worked now. I needed to replace every androidx  import by migrating to appcompat support

Answer (score 1):

Try to migrate to AppCompat...

Refactor > Migrate to AppCompat...

But such as Peter Alwin spoke, "android does not support both androidX and support library at the same time".